What Causes Hand- Wound and Machine-Wound Motors to Have Different kV? Expected Efficiency and Power Differences?
I am trying to understand the motor power and efficiency of two identical motors with the only difference being the winding technique (hand-wound and machine-wound).
Both are essentially the same hub bike motors with 4 turns. According to the manufacturer, the machine-wound motor is rated at 12 kV, while the hand-wound one is rated at 13.2 kV. Visually, the machine-wound motor has much tighter and cleaner-looking winding, but possibly with a slightly lower copper fill.
What can be expected— which of the motors should be more powerful, efficient, and overall better, and why?
I am assuming that the back EMF in the lower kV variant is higher, which causes the lower maximum RPM. However, I can't find reliable information on how that affects the power and efficiency of the motor.

Is "hub bike" a translation error? I can't imagine any bicycle having that much voltage on it, let alone the power that must imply (10s, 100s MVA?).

kV in this context is 1000s of RPM/volt at no load.

I mean RPM/V.  Maybe KV or Kv is the right term.

@ВладимирПетров K is Kelvin, measure of temperature ... k is kilo, meaning 1000 ... V is voltage, not v
